# Send video stream from android device

Tags: video-streaming

I'm new in android. I was planning to create a Video streaming mobile to mobile in the same wifi connnection but i don't know how to start. I've read about the RTP/RTSP/UDP for streaming video and some sources but I cant follow the process at all. Can someone explain to me how to send or broadcast a video playing in android device then send the data in a server? So that it can be access in like "rtsp//: something like that so that the other device can view it. Sorry for the small info

Answer (score 2):

For most mundane purposes related to your question, there's a really good solution:

DroidCam (or DroidCamX, for PRO version)

- https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dev47apps.droidcam
- https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dev47apps.droidcamx&hl=en&gl=US
- https://www.dev47apps.com/

I use the PRO version for unlimited streaming resolution. For about $3-4 bucks I have a software that streams the video from my Android phone from a camera of choice (front, back, back wide-angle), over the wire to the PC (works perfectly with Ubuntu Linux and Windows), or over WiFi connection to the LAN. As longs as you have a static local IP address assigned within your LAN, your camera stream is available through the port of choice.
Linux and Windows PC clients have options to control autofocus. Android-side software has options for optimizing stream bitrate and quality ("Limit FPS", "FPS Boost").

This is one of the very few paid apps I've had so far, I predominantly use it as a substitute for a web camera (a rather cheap one).

Answer (score 1):

There are two things involved in this.
 1. Implementation of RTSP
 2. Converting android camera output into RTSP source.

I could not find any open implementation while I was searching for it almost 6 months back. Here is the one which worked for me with little tuning. But you have to clone the repo and work on it directly to get it working
https://github.com/mutaphore/RTSP-Client-Server